# Python: while loop in noughts and crosses

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have coded a game of noughts and crosses, and am using a while loop to run the game. However, I must be doing something wrong as I cannot get it to print 'You win' or 'You lose' when a row/column/diagonal of X or O is on the board. I know the function that checks the board works as I have tested it on its own, by putting Xs in the board manually, but when playing the game normally it completely disregards any Xs or Os in 3. Here is the code, sorry it's abit long. Thanks

```
import random

board = [
['1','-','-','-'],
['2','-','-','-'],
['3','-','-','-'],
['#','1','2','3'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ']
]

rows = {
    'top':
    board[0][1:],
    'mid':
    board[1][1:],
    'bottom':
    board[2][1:]
}

cols = {
    'left':
    [board[0][1],
    board[1][1],
    board[2][1]],
    'mid':
    [board[0][2],
    board[1][2],
    board[2][2]],
    'right':
    [board[0][3],
    board[1][3],
    board[2][3]]
}

diags = {
    'top-bottom':
    [board[0][1],
    board[1][2],
    board[2][3]],
    'bottom-top':
    [board[2][1],
    board[1][2],
    board[0][3]]
}

gamestate = 1

def print_board(board):
    for i in board:
        print " ".join(i)

def win_check(rows,cols,diags):
    plrWin = ['X','X','X']
    cpuWin = ['O','O','O']
    global gamestate
    for i in rows.values():
        if i == plrWin:
            return True
            gamestate = 0

        elif i == cpuWin:
            return False
            gamestate = 0


    for x in cols.values():
        if x == plrWin:
                return True
            gamestate = 0

        elif x == cpuWin:
            return False
            gamestate = 0



    for y in diags.values():
        if y == plrWin:
            return True
            gamestate = 0

    elif y == cpuWin:
        return False
        gamestate = 0





def game_entry():
    print "Your turn."
    coordY = input("Guess column: ")
    coordX = input("Guess row: ")
    board[coordX - 1][coordY] = 'X'

def random_location():
    while True:
        cpuX = random.randint(1,3)
        cpuY = random.randint(1,3)
        if (board[cpuX - 1][cpuY] == 'X') or (board[cpuX - 1][cpuY] == 'O'):
            continue
        else:
            board[cpuX - 1][cpuY] = 'O'
            break


while gamestate == 1:
    print_board(board)
    game_entry()
    random_location()
    if win_check(rows,cols,diags) == True:
        print "You win!"
        gamestate = 0
        break
    elif win_check(rows,cols,diags) == False:
        print "You lose."
        gamestate = 0
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down to where you are getting the error or where you think you are?

Comment: @squiguy There's no error specifically, it just doesn't work the way it should. When there is a row full of Xs, it won't display "You win" and end the program, it just keeps going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with all of the `rows` and `cols` dictionaries:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> x = l[0][1:]
>>> x
[2, 3]
>>> l[0][1] = 4
>>> x
[2, 3]
```

As you can see, they don't update when the board is changed. You'll have to find another way of doing this.

I would just use a few loops and check the diagonals manually:

```
def has_someone_won(board):
    # Rows
    for row in board:
        if row[0] == row[1] == row[2] != '-':
            return True

    # Columns
    for i in range(3):
        if board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] != '-':
            return True

    # Diagonal 1
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != '-':
        return True

    # Diagonal 2
    if board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2] != '-':
        return True

    # There's no winner
    return False
```

Comment: Just tried this, but it will just return True every time as the placeholder characters ('-') are the same. Unless I make every grid character different, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user2253076: Well, I'm not going to write the whole thing for you. Figure it out.